# Fixing flaky nunit tests

Tags: c#, multithreading, continuous-integration, nunit

I want to fix flaky tests that are semi-sensitive to resource availability.

In the local machine, when you run all the tests they will likely all pass without an issue, especially when ran 1 by 1. However there are about +10k tests and ~60 of them have anywhere from 0.01%-20% chance to fail when ran on Team City Continuous Integration build agents. The CI build + running all the tests and other stuff takes 6m:40s - 18m:30s. The chances of resource congestion can be increased by having multiple agents on the same server, basically having high load in 1 will impact the other

[image: CI Builds showing fails]

The tests that fail are using multiple threads or reactive extension observables and observe on thread pool. In following example the pipline runner extends [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx).

```
    [Test]
    public void Cancel_CancelsAllProcessingAtOnce()
    {
        var items1 = 0;
        var items2 = 0;
        var pipe = Pipeline.For<int>()
            .AddAction(x => { Thread.Sleep(10); items1++; }, 1)
            .AddAction(x => { Thread.Sleep(20); items2++; }, 1);
        var runner = PipelineRunner.For(pipe);
        Task.Run(() => runner.Run(Enumerable.Range(0, 100)));
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        runner.Cancel();

        var lastBlock = pipe.Blocks.Last().Blocks.Last();

        lastBlock.Completion.Wait();

        Assert.IsTrue(lastBlock.Completion.IsCompleted);
        items1.Should().BeLessThan(1000);
        items1.Should().BeGreaterThan(items2);
    }
```

In normal state this would be fine, but if not given enough resources then items1 and items2 will be 0 and equal, but there are various other invalid states. In case of observables, it seems that usually ~1 subscribers of stream of following stream will fail to produce answer if test is going to await fixed amount of time.

```
        var reportStream = _subject.BuildFilteredStream(runner.ReportsRaw, reportTypes)
            .SubscribeOn(testScheduler.TaskPool)
            .ObserveOn(testScheduler.TaskPool);
```

---

I have tried running the test fixures in Non Parallelizable STA apartment state

```
[NonParallelizable]
[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
```

Making the test run in deterministic order by specifying the order attribute, requires thread, setting higher timeouts, using the retry attribute (even 10 will fail...) changing some old tests to stop using thread sleep and waits to delay and awaits for async task. Ex:
[image]

I want to keep cases where there are multiple agents on same server, and for large majority of test running them in parallel should be possible. What I seem to need is the ability to run tests when CPU utilization does not exceed 80%, allocating of threads is possible, or something like that, however this seemingly exceeds what I can do with nunit.

What should I try?

Comment: The way you're spinning up the "thread" (actually a task, Task.Run), bloack (Thread.Sleep) and await (.Wait()) it, looks a bit suspicious. Can't you make the test a Task itself and use the async/await/Task pattern all the way?

Comment: @Stefan I can (I have), but that will not fix the issue (and that's a problem). I do not want to make potential side-effects to code written by other just because I have a preference.

Comment: Still you don't need to block in your tests

Comment: @AluanHaddad I agree, I can include those changes, but I still need to find a way to actually fix or have reliable automatic work-a-round for the main issue that causes sporadic assertion fails in tests.

Comment: To what extent what do you say that the resource contention observed in the tests reflects the resource contention on the server when the app is running

Comment: One point - I think you might have mixed up `RepeatAttribute` and `RetryAttribute`. You've written in this question that you've tried RepeatAttribute - but that would only make things worse in this situation. I think RetryAttribute is what you're looking for instead - check out the difference in the docs. =)

Comment: @Chris Yes, I meant vanilla Retry attribute. 

I did also contemplate on Extending NUnit Retry https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/e3db502f121a9d9bdbf0dca70b2ba55f27365571/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/RetryAttribute.cs with a performance goal policy with a timeout. If I do not find a better solution, will create a pull request for it.